# Optimal params size for MySQL IN(..) predicate

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have many PK ids for some InnoDB MySQL's table.
I want to delete records by PK as fast as possible.
Ids are totally randomized and there is no way to delete them by intervals.
I suppose that the best way is delete them by IN(...) predicate

But if I put it all to a single DELETE FROM T WHERE id IN(...) it works to looong : 1-2 hours for 1.5 millions recs.

Probably, I should split it to some batches, but what size of batch will be the most optimal?

Comment: Another possibility, put the ids into a temp table. Then join you main table to the temp table in the DELETE statement, deleting the matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The best is ONE query. No batches.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be increased to speedup table reordering on disk.

otherwise:

If u DONT have `CONSTRAINT`s in your table, use MyIsam instead.

otherwise:

i believe you should find more memory for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: I can't increase any memory parameter because of hard memory limit

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

If you are deleting more than half the table, instead do

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
2. `INSERT ...` to copy the desired rows to `new`.
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`

(Caveat:  I don't know if "half" is optimal.)

**Case 2**

If you can sort the do so.  That will decrease the amount of back and forth that might happen in the table.

Do batch them; perhaps 1000 at a time.  Why?  For InnoDB, this limits home much "undo" information must be logged in case it crashes.  And turn on autocommit so that each batch will close out the undo log.